# How to "open with" NTemacs on Windows?

Tags: windows, emacs

I have just installed `ntemacs` and I would like to open `.txt` files with it by default. The only executable that it will open with is `emacs.exe`, but this open a command line window as well and it would be good if I can just get it to open without the command line window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `runemacs.exe` rather than `emacs.exe`.

Comment: Ah I thought it didn't work, so I tried again and it does

Answer (score 0):

I create the following bat script (usually called `emacsc`) and associate it with text files and the like

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" goto noargs
"%~dp0\emacs-24.0.50\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -na "%~dp0\emacs-24.0.50\bin\runemacs.exe" %*
goto exit
:noargs
"%~dp0\emacs-24.0.50\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -na "%~dp0\emacs-24.0.50\bin\runemacs.exe" -e *scratch*

:exit
```

I also add it to the path so that if I run `emacsc` from the command line.